# Set dbGetQuery to return integer64 as integer

Tags: r, integer, odbc, dplyr, r-dbi

By default when I use `dbGetQuery()` from the `DBI` package it returns columns of type `integer64` as the `integer64` class of the `bit64`.

I then use `dplyr` to try and filter and manipulate my results but come into issues as `dplyr` does not support objects of type `integer64`.

Is it possible to set `dbGetQuery()` to return `integer64` columns as class `integer`?

Comment: Why not just convert to integer after calling `dbGetQuery()` instead of doing it at that stage?

Comment: I think your three options will be: (a) Michael's suggest to convert to integer post-query; (b) use SQL's `CAST(... as integer32)` within the query; or (c) take it to the issues board for whichever ODBC driver you are using (perhaps [`odbc`](https://github.com/rstats-db/odbc/issues)). I think the latter is most appropriate for the long-term, but since `bit64` is still not globally used/accepted in R, it may be an uphill battle.

Comment: "Why not just convert to integer after calling dbGetQuery() instead of doing it at that stage? "

It would have been neater to do it using an argument or something within dbGetQuery, but if there is no better way of doing it then I guess I'll have to

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The DBI spec provides this functionality via the `bigint` argument. Support will obviously vary between drivers.

```
dbConnect(drv, bigint="integer", ...)
```

The following values behave as follows:

> "integer": always return as integer, silently overflow
>
> "numeric": always return as numeric, silently round
>
> "character": always return the decimal representation as character
>
> "integer64": return as a data type that can be coerced using as.integer() 
>   (with warning on overflow), as.numeric() and as.character()

Source:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DBI/vignettes/spec.html#_specification_17

Comment: thank you - this worked for me and saved me!!!

Answer (score 14):

Even without full support of 64-bit integers (see [GitHub issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/1092)), you still can use dplyr to mutate away from `integer64`:

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
df <- data_frame(a = bit64::as.integer64(1:3), b = 1:3, c = 1.5:4)
df
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>                 a     b     c
#>   <S3: integer64> <int> <dbl>
#> 1               1     1   1.5
#> 2               2     2   2.5
#> 3               3     3   3.5
df %>% mutate_if(bit64::is.integer64, as.integer)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>       a     b     c
#>   <int> <int> <dbl>
#> 1     1     1   1.5
#> 2     2     2   2.5
#> 3     3     3   3.5
```